# My Principled BSDF is not fully showing up

Tags: interface, shader-nodes

When I go in the Shader Editor, my Principled BSDF is much shorter than all the ones I see in tutorials.

This is what it looks like when I do it

[image]

This is what it looks like in every tutorial I see

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since version 4.0, the Principled BSDF have seen quite significant changes, both in therms of user interface and functionality:

[image]

The main "global" properties are exposed as is, while other "layers" are in individual panels that you can open, toggle ON/OFF with the Weight property, and the settings inside are a bit different from the old Principled BSDF.

> The base layer is a mix between metal, diffuse, subsurface, and transmission components. Most materials will use one of these components, though it is possible to smoothly mix between them.
> [image: schematic of principled BSDF layers]
>
> The metal component is opaque and only reflect lights. Diffuse is fully opaque, while subsurface also involves light scattering just below the surface. Both diffuse and subsurface sit below a specular layer. The transmission component includes both specular reflection and refraction.
>
> On top of all base layers there is an optional glossy coat. And finally the sheen layer sits on top of all other layers, to add fuzz or dust.
>
> Light emission can also be added. Light emits from below the coat and sheen layers, to model for example emissive displays with a coat or dust.
>
> ---
>
> Source: [**Principled BSDF — Blender Manual**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html#coat)

[Christopher 3D](https://www.youtube.com/@christopher3d475) did quite a few videos going in detail about the shorcomings of the previous Principled BSDF, how the new one solves them, and how to use it.

See his playlist: [Blender 4.0 Feature Videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIsEkSjZmz1r9EAFuwwjCSVkh5n-NJ26e)

Comment: I want to make it see-through with the transmission feature.
In the video when he changes the transmission it looks see through when for me it looks like a slimy blob

Comment: That's a different topic. First, if you are using Eevee, there are additional settings to change in order to get transmission to work properly, there are many topics talking about this so please search for that first if you use Eevee. Otherwise, please make a new question, and include screenshots of what you want to achieve, the result you get, and your shader so that we can see what you did.

Answer (score 3):

This is how the *Principled BSDF* looks in the latest versions, they made it shorter but everything is about the same, you need to click on the small arrows to unfold the part you want.

Comment: I have done that but it doesn't seem to work. I want to use the translucent feature but it doesn't change anything. 

Comment: translucent is not part of the Principled BSDF, you need to press Shift A > Shader > Translucent BSDF to get this shader